# Rails is not finding one of my routes [PATCH]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, config

I have a users edit form, and whenever I try to submit said form, I get the following error:

```
    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/users/1/edit")
```

Here is my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = 'Signup Successful!'
      log_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile Updated!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end

  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                 :password_confirmation)
    end

    def logged_in_user
      if !(logged_in?)
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in"
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

  end
```

My routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup', to: 'users#create'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
end
```

I also ran rake routes in order to make sure that I had all the routes I needed, and I found the PATCH route for users in it:

```
PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
```

I've tried to find the bug for two hours, but to no avail (as is why I'm posting here)

Here is my form partial:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: url) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

and here's my edit.html.erb

```
<%provide(:title, 'Edit')%>
<%provide(:button_text, 'Save Changes')%>
<h1>Edit</h1>

<div class = 'row'>
    <div class = 'col-md-6 col-md-offset-3' >
        <%=render 'form', url: edit_user_path(@user)%>
        <div class = "gravatar-edit">
            <%=gravatar_for @user%>
            <a href = "http://gravatar.com/emails", target = '_blank'>Change</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- Thanks in advance

Comment: In your HTML, you're calling `[PATCH] "/users/1/edit"` but your actual route is `PATCH  /users/1`. Show the HTML and form.

Comment: I uploaded the html and form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found the problem.

So basically, as Max Pleaner pointed out, I'm calling `[PATCH] "/users/1/edit"` when it should be `PATCH /users/1.` So, I changed my URL argument in my edit.html.erb file

from:

`<%=render 'form', url: edit_user_path(@user)%>`

to:

`<%=render 'form', url: user_path(@user)%>`

Answer (score 0):

The REST verb for the route you are trying to access is GET, because usually the "edit" action is used to render a form to edit the object (in this case the user). If you want to use the PATCH verb to update an user you should in your case PATCH to "/users/1"